# Giving Value to Python3 Count String

Tags: count, python-3.7

I am running a loop equation that divides or subtracts. Every time it divides I want it to represent each division with the # 2 and every time it subtracts I want it to represent the subtractions with a 1. I then want that count string to be a value that I can manipulate with some basic math. Basically it'll look like this: 20/2 = 10 (2) 10/2 = 5 (2) 5/2 = 2.5 (2) 2.5-.5 = 2 (1) 2/2 = 1 (2)
22212 <=== that I want to make a new value but with the way I have it coded, it's not working. I think it may have something to do with the end='' in the code.

I've tried giving the value of the string = to a int value and tried joining the string but no luck so far.

```
num = 20
while num >= 1.5:
        num /= 2
        v = 1
        print(v, end='')
        if int(num) != num:
            num -= .5
            v = 2
            print(v, end='') #trying to make the output here a value
            nv = ''.join(str(int(v)))
            nv = int(v) #trying to give the joined strs of nv a value
print(nv) #trying to get this to print the combined valued of v to something that math can be applied to.
print('')
```

The code doesn't give any errors I just can't figure out how to make the output and actual number that I can manipulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are printing v = 1 after your division. In your post you said you want a 2 for division, I am assuming what you wrote in the post is the result you want.

```
a = ""
num = 20
while num >= 1.5:
    num /= 2
    a +=  "2"
    if int(num) != num:
        num -= .5
        a += "1"
print(a)
```

now a is a string with your desired result. You can always convert that String to an int to do some math with it.